# How to split on dataframe column into two another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split on column named as "variable" into two another column "Type" and "Parameter"

```
  BatchNumber PhaseNumber SiteID   variable  Values
0  4552694035       0020B      2  min_tempC    27.0
1  4552694035     OverAll      2  max_tempF    24.0
```

I tried to use below code

```
weatherData = weatherData['variable'].str.split('_', 1)
```

But not getting expected result.
The expected result is as below.

```
  BatchNumber PhaseNumber SiteID   variable  Values     Type    Parameter
0  4552694035       0020B      2  min_tempC    27.0     min     tempC
1  4552694035     OverAll      2  max_tempF    24.0     max     tempF
```

Any body knows.. how to get it?

Comment: Thanks its working with your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and parameter `expand=True` for `DataFrame`:

```
weatherData[['Type','Parameter']]=weatherData.pop('variable').str.split('_', 1, expand=True)
print (weatherData)
   BatchNumber PhaseNumber  SiteID  Values Type Parameter
0   4552694035       0020B       2    27.0  min     tempC
1   4552694035     OverAll       2    24.0  max     tempF
```

If want also original column remove `pop`:

```
weatherData[['Type','Parameter']] = weatherData['variable'].str.split('_', 1, expand=True)
print (weatherData)
   BatchNumber PhaseNumber  SiteID   variable  Values Type Parameter
0   4552694035       0020B       2  min_tempC    27.0  min     tempC
1   4552694035     OverAll       2  max_tempF    24.0  max     tempF
```

Comment: Looks like OP does not want the column popped out

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['Type'], df['Parameter'] = df['variable'].str.split('_')

#    BatchNumber PhaseNumber  SiteID   variable  Values   Type Parameter
# 0   4552694035       0020B       2  min_tempC    27.0    min       max
# 1   4552694035     OverAll       2  max_tempF    24.0  tempC     tempF
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `assign`, `zip`, and `dict` unpacking

```
df.assign(**dict(zip(('Type', 'Parameter'), zip(*df.variable.str.split('_')))))

   BatchNumber PhaseNumber  SiteID   variable  Values Type Parameter
0   4552694035       0020B       2  min_tempC    27.0  min     tempC
1   4552694035     OverAll       2  max_tempF    24.0  max     tempF
```